# Joda Time and timezone offsets

Tags: jodatime

I have a problem with timezone offsets in Joda Time. I think it is simply a problem uf understanding.

I have the following parser and printer:

```
// The formatter for the timezone
    DateTimeFormatter timezoneFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendTimeZoneOffset(null, true, 2, 2)
                .toFormatter();

    // This formatter equals: yyyy-MM-dd
    DateTimeFormatter dhmsFormatter = ISODateTimeFormat.date();

    // Here a parser is created that parses a string of the form yyyy-MM-dd. Further the string may have
    // a timezone. withOffsetParsed makes the parser to respect the set timezone (if one is set)
    DATE_TIME_PARSER = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().append(dhmsFormatter)
                .appendOptional(timezoneFormatter.getParser()).toFormatter().withOffsetParsed();

    // Here a printer is created that prints this dateTime in the form yyyy-MM-dd ZZ
    DATE_TIME_PRINTER = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().append(dhmsFormatter).append(timezoneFormatter.getPrinter()).toFormatter();
```

This works as expected when I parse and print dates that have an offset set. E.g.:

- 2006-11-11-09:00
- 2004-12-01+00:00

Those two values are parsed and printed as they are written above here.

Now my question:
I want to be able to set a default time zone (i.e. default offset when none is set).
I'll do that like this:
`DateTimeZone.setDefault(DateTimeZone.forID("Etc/GMT+1"));`

My expectation is now that `2006-11-11` is parsed and printed as `2006-11-11+01:00`, but in fact it prints `2006-11-11-01:00`.

I think this is somehow correct because here http://www.joda.org/joda-time/timezones.html it is written that Etc/GMT+1 has the standard offset of -01:00.
So what's wrong?
I want to offset to reflect the GMT-offset.
I also think that my values above are wrong: means `2006-11-11-09:00` is not the timezone of "Japan" but it is the timezone of "US/Alaska".

I hope my problem is clear.
Does anybody have an answer for my not-understanding :)?

Best regards,
Florian

Answer (score 1):

Can it be that you instantiate `DateTimeFormatter` or a `DateTime` before setting a default timezone?

Anyway, I believe [`withZone()`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#withZone%28org.joda.time.DateTimeZone%29) method should give you the formatter/parser you're looking for.

Comment: No this is done right. My problem is that something is strange (for me) with the offset. GMT+1 has an offset of -01:00. But I thing the offset should be +01:00.

Comment: Oh, then this is probably the (incomplete) answer to your question: http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090707145844AANnghH